# Variable declaration Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling

Cannot re-declare variable 'greet' with scope 'Block'.

I started learning Typescript, and when declared variable and variable type and launched to see result, it returned error

- Cannot re-declare variable 'greet' with scope 'Block'.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to translate the error message? What is the rationale for trying to redeclare or reassing a value to a constant?

Comment: Yes as I use russian version of Visual studio code, I did translate

Comment: `const`: ["_... identifier cannot be reassigned ... cannot share its name with a function or a variable in the same scope._"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#description).

Comment: Screenshots of IDEs are not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: Screenshot was for explaining the situation.

Solution was found. Thank you for Hazik Arshad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your file to an ESModule, like this:

```
// ✅ variable declared successfully
const name = 'Coding Beauty';

console.log(name); // Coding Beauty

export {};
```

Or

You can do this by using nested block designated with curly braces:

```
let color = 'red';

{
  let color = 'yellow';

  console.log(color); // yellow
}

console.log(color); // red
```

Comment: see [ask] on answering poorly asked questions.